# Click on form area using Selenium with python javascript execute_script not working

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

The HTML tag form with id **deadDrop** is a file drop area. I need to click on this area and then I will drop the file using selenium.

Nothing happens when the line in python script executes. When I execute below script on chrome console the form is clicked.

document.getElementById('deadDrop').click()

driver.find_element().send_keys() works on pycharm while running locally, but that fails when run on Jenkins. So I'm looking for alternatives to upload file. There is no delay, I have custom wait and driver object is waiting till this form appears.

### Selenium script

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('deadDrop').click()")

### HTML Element

```
<form id="deadDrop" class="dropzone dropzoneTT needsclick ng-pristine ng-valid dz-clickable layout-align-start-center layout-row" dropzone="dropzoneConfig" layout="row" layout-align="left center" ng-click="uploadCustomFile()" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <div>
      <md-icon md-svg-src="/static/icons/uploadFile.svg" class="fileIcon" aria-hidden="true">
         <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 51 54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false">
            <g opacity="0.8">
               <path d="M38.1659 23.7946V13.8078C38.1659 13.5219 38.0258 13.2578 37.8275 13.0488L25.9458 1.29132C25.7241 1.07149 25.4088 0.950302 25.0939 0.950302H6.25574C2.77795 0.950302 0 3.62285 0 6.90053V40.4684C0 43.7461 2.77795 46.3748 6.25574 46.3748H21.1256C23.9382 50.7741 29.0506 53.7217 34.8744 53.7217C43.7214 53.7217 50.9461 46.9465 50.9461 38.5987C50.9581 31.3066 45.4022 25.2134 38.1659 23.7946ZM26.2611 4.81096L34.2327 12.7187H29.0621C27.5215 12.7187 26.2611 11.5201 26.2611 10.0683V4.81096ZM6.25574 44.1749C4.07336 44.1749 2.33447 42.525 2.33447 40.4684V6.90053C2.33447 4.8327 4.07336 3.15018 6.25574 3.15018H23.9266V10.0683C23.9266 12.7408 26.2261 14.9186 29.0621 14.9186H35.8314V23.5083C35.4815 23.4975 35.2012 23.4645 34.8979 23.4645C30.8245 23.4645 27.078 24.9384 24.2535 27.2482H9.4306C8.78845 27.2482 8.26337 27.743 8.26337 28.3478C8.26337 28.9529 8.78845 29.4477 9.4306 29.4477H22.0826C21.2538 30.5476 20.5651 31.6476 20.0284 32.8574H9.4306C8.78845 32.8574 8.26337 33.3522 8.26337 33.9574C8.26337 34.5621 8.78845 35.0573 9.4306 35.0573H19.2697C18.9778 36.1572 18.8262 37.378 18.8262 38.5987C18.8262 40.5783 19.2346 42.5363 19.9699 44.1862H6.25574V44.1749ZM34.8863 51.5331C27.3232 51.5331 21.1722 45.7366 21.1722 38.6096C21.1722 31.4825 27.3113 25.6861 34.8863 25.6861C42.461 25.6861 48.6001 31.4825 48.6001 38.6096C48.6001 45.7366 42.4495 51.5331 34.8863 51.5331Z"></path>
               <path d="M9.43085 23.9375H21.254C21.8962 23.9375 22.4213 23.4423 22.4213 22.8376C22.4213 22.2325 21.8962 21.7376 21.254 21.7376H9.43085C8.7887 21.7376 8.26361 22.2325 8.26361 22.8376C8.26361 23.4423 8.7887 23.9375 9.43085 23.9375Z"></path>
               <path d="M35.715 30.4925C35.4933 30.2727 35.1899 30.1406 34.8631 30.1406C34.5363 30.1406 34.2329 30.2727 34.0112 30.4925L27.1714 37.4106C26.7279 37.8506 26.7629 38.5544 27.2299 38.9615C27.6969 39.3794 28.4553 39.3464 28.8988 38.9067L33.7309 34.0343V46.0446C33.7309 46.6498 34.256 47.1446 34.8981 47.1446C35.5399 47.1446 36.0654 46.6498 36.0654 46.0446V34.0343L40.8621 38.9067C41.0958 39.1374 41.3991 39.2586 41.7144 39.2586C41.9943 39.2586 42.2745 39.1595 42.5078 38.9615C42.9748 38.5435 43.0098 37.8506 42.5664 37.4106L35.715 30.4925Z"></path>
            </g>
         </svg>
      </md-icon>
   </div>
   <div layout="column" class="layout-column">
      <div ng-show="!taxTransition.existingTaxLotsFile" aria-hidden="false" class="">
         <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            <h5 class="dropBoxMsg">Upload tax lots of an account</h5>
            <div class="dropBoxSubMsg">Or drag-and-drop a file here</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="taxTransition.existingTaxLotsFile" aria-hidden="true" class="ng-hide">
         <div class="dz-default dz-message">
            <h5 class="dropBoxMsg ng-binding"></h5>
            <!--<div class="dropBoxSubMsg">Upload existing cost basis</div>-->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1) Can you provide a link to that page? 2) Why are you using driver.execute_script and not driver.find_element? 3) Is it possibly you have to add delay or iframe there?

Comment: Actually I can't share the link, it will not be accessible publicly, the server is in intranet.

Comment: What about the other questions?

Comment: driver.find_element(<xpath>).send_keys(<file location>) works on pycharm while running locally, but that fails when run on Jenkins. So I'm looking for alternatives to upload file.

There is no delay, I have custom wait and driver object is waiting till this form appears.

Comment: OK, now it's clearer. You should give all this information inside the question..
Is there input element on the page? Normally above the form element? Can you provide the entire page HTML?

Comment: @Prophet I attached that on G drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/13YX8lJ8Uy4LSFq4q4QajbeX1DvHHupPc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see it as visible formatted HTML...

Comment: Yes, links will be broken, lot of data and scripts on this page. I'll try to find out the input for this form. Thanks.

Comment: In case there is such a input element try sending to it the path where the file you need to upload is located on the hard disk. This will upload it to the page.
I'm not sure, but hope this will help

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, what to do if that input is hidden, visibility is hidden.

Comment: O! I'm facing with this issue currently :) Still don't know. Saw several answers here, no one helped. But the problems are with FireFox, with Crome it works fine.